# docker-compose denied by AppArmor outside of $HOME - how to fix?

Tags: permissions, 20.04, docker, apparmor

I'm trying to run `docker-compose up` from `/data/myproject` but it fails:

```
/data/myproject# docker-compose up
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

Apparently it's due to AppArmor blocking that access because the `docker-compose.yml` certainly is present in the directory and the same `docker-compose.yml` works from my `$HOME`. Only when I move it to `/data` it doesn't.

```
/data/myproject# dmesg | tail
...
[62950.885492] audit: type=1400 audit(1591658453.915:144): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.compose" name="/proc/7429/mounts" pid=7429 comm="python3" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[63016.064496] audit: type=1400 audit(1591658519.090:145): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.compose" name="/proc/7476/mounts" pid=7476 comm="python3" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[63043.767933] audit: type=1400 audit(1591658546.793:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.compose" name="/proc/7505/mounts" pid=7505 comm="python3" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

My question: **How do I add `/data` to permitted directories for `docker` / `docker-compose`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we focus only on the AVC denial it can be eliminated from the logs by modifying

```
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.compose
```

Adding:

```
@{PROC}/@{pid}/mounts r,
```

Then reloading the profile:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.compose
```

This actually **did not make docker-compose work**. It just deals that particular denial. So I don’t recommend it.

The most important aspect of this may be that docker is installed as a snap.

The broader issue is highlighted here:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6361

On this thread to date contributors have worked around it by installing docker compose from apt rather than using the snap.

Digging a little bit more into that the docker snap suggests that needing to use the $HOME directory is a known limitation.
https://github.com/docker-archive/docker-snap#usage

From there I think the question will relate to limitations in the docker snap rather than AppArmor denying something.

I’ve left the original suggestion below because it may help in other situations.

**Old answer**

The program aa-logprof can be used to scan log files for AppArmor audit messages, review them and update the profiles.

```
sudo aa-logprof
```

It might guide you through the process without you needing to dive into the nuts and bolts of AppArmor.

Here is the man page:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/aa-logprof.8.html

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't do much: `Reading log entries from /var/log/syslog.
Updating AppArmor profiles in /etc/apparmor.d.` - that's all. No questions asked and problem not fixed either.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have uninstalled the snap and installed the official docker-ce - problem sorted. Thanks again :)